# IllegalStateException: Location is not set. JavaFX and Maven

Tags: java, maven, javafx, jar

Im am trying to build a .jar file using Maven. I am really new to Maven, but this is my task at college so I need to use it.

Everything works when starting my project in Eclipse. But when I build a .jar and try to run it I get this:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unk
nown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Sou
rce)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown So
urce)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$156(
Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException:

        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
        at de.ostfalia.ftswt.MainApp.start(MainApp.java:32)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$163
(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$176(Unknown
 Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$174(Unknown Sourc
e)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$175(Unknown S
ource)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
        at de.ostfalia.ftswt.MainController.initialize(MainController.java:35)
        ... 22 more
```

My pom.xml seems pretty long to me and I don't know if everything is needed, but this is what my project partner gave to me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>de.ostfalia.ftswt</groupId>
    <artifactId>client</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>client</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <mainClass>de.ostfalia.ftswt.MainApp</mainClass>
    </properties>

      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-jaxb</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludeScope>system</excludeScope>
                            <excludeGroupIds>junit,org.mockito,org.hamcrest</excludeGroupIds>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-dependencies</id>

                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>${java.home}/../bin/javafxpackager</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>-createjar</argument>
                                <argument>-nocss2bin</argument>
                                <argument>-appclass</argument>
                                <argument>${mainClass}</argument>
                                <argument>-srcdir</argument>
                                <argument>${project.build.directory}/classes</argument>
                                <argument>-outdir</argument>
                                <argument>${project.build.directory}</argument>
                                <argument>-outfile</argument>
                                <argument>${project.build.finalName}.jar</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>                            
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>${java.home}/bin/java</executable>
                            <commandlineArgs>${runfx.args}</commandlineArgs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>  
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <bootclasspath>${sun.boot.class.path}${path.separator}${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</bootclasspath>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalClasspathElements>
                        <additionalClasspathElement>${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</additionalClasspathElement>
                    </additionalClasspathElements>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

We are working with RESTEasy to provide some data sets on an application server.
This application is going to be our client-application which uses these data sets to show some JavaFX diagrams.

The problem seems to be that the FXMLLoader can't find my .fxml files. 
We started with an example project(which worked) and the structure of the project is still the same, so I don't see why this wouldn't work...

This is where I try to load the .fxml file:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("MainPane.fxml"));
Parent root = loader.load();
```

The .fxml files are placed in src/main/resources.

Maybe there is just something wrong with my pom, but I have no more ideas what to do, so I hoped maybe anyone here would find the mistake.

Comment: If you log the URL generated by `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("MainPane.fxml")`, what does it give? Does that resource look right?

Comment: Where is the `MainPane.fxml` located in your project?

Comment: Yes, it looks right and I am pretty sure that this is the right path. I tried the same with the jar file from the example project and this gives me a similar path which works.

Comment: MainPane.fxml is located in src/main/resources.
So it is placed in the root directory of my jar file.

Comment: So try with `getResource("/MainPane.fxml")`

Comment: I tried  getResource("/MainPane.fxml")  but the problem still exists.
It returns the same path as when using "MainPane.fxml" an I still get this Exception.

Comment: What do you get from logging the URL? Can you verify it exists in the jar file (assuming it gives you a jar:// URL). You can just execute `jar -tf jarfile` from the command line to inspect the jar file contents.

Comment: I've found the problem! It was not the MainPane.fxml but its controller. The MainPane-Controller also tried to load another .fxml, but I accidently used a lower-case letter instead of upper-case in the name of the .fxml. So it couldn't find this file in the jar.  Thank you James_D for the hint to log getResource(). It just took a little time to realize that this controller is also loading .fxml files at this time.